# Deploy HuggingFace models to AWS: configuration file needed on local machine

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to deploy this model to AWS through Sagemaker:
https://huggingface.co/mosaicml/mpt-7b-chat

I generated the code from the same page which is as follow:

```
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFaceModel
import sagemaker

role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
# Hub Model configuration. https://huggingface.co/models
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID':'mosaicml/mpt-7b-chat',
    'HF_TASK':'text-generation'
}

# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    transformers_version='4.17.0',
    pytorch_version='1.10.2',
    py_version='py38',
    env=hub,
    role=role, 
)

# deploy model to SageMaker Inference
predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, # number of instances
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge' # ec2 instance type
)

predictor.predict({
    'inputs': "Can you please let us know more details about your "
})
```

The code crash at the "predict" call with this error:
Loading /.sagemaker/mms/models/mosaicml__mpt-7b-chat requires you to execute the configuration file in that repo on your local machine. Make sure you have read the code there to avoid malicious use, then set the option `trust_remote_code\u003dTrue` to remove this error.

how can I deploy the model through AWS?

Comment: Can you try deploying via a larger instance and see if the same error persists? Another option is also downloading the HF model artifacts directly and creating your own tarball file and testing that. If you could share the entirety of the CW logs that would be helpful.

Comment: HF discussion - https://github.com/huggingface/text-generation-inference/issues/361
I couldn't find a way to set the param successfully either.